# Who can explain the name "pull request' in git?

Tags: git, naming

Who can explain the name "pull request' in git?

Because it is a workflow method for submitting contributions.

My question is just about the name 'pull'.
I understand the 'request' part.
What or which pulling do they mean?
Why is push request, submit request not better?
Note that I belong to the class of non-native "english" speakers.

Comment: Because you request the owner of the other repo to pull into their repo some changes that are present into your repo. What you do is to put the changes into a buffer area (the PR) and nicely ask the owner of the other repo to get them. When they accept, they pull them into their repo.

Comment: This is actually understandable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/)

Pull requests let you tell others about changes you've pushed to a repository on GitHub. Once a pull request is opened, you can discuss and review the potential changes with collaborators and add follow-up commits before the changes are merged into the repository.

Since its the request made to the target to pull your artifacts it's called a pull request

Answer (score 0):

Push and pull are relative terms (and they have specific meanings in git).

Let's suppose you have two repos A and B. Now, suppose you'd like to merge additional commits on repo A to repo B. There are two ways to do it. (1) You can push (the commits) from A to B (if you have proper permission on repo B). Or, (2) you can pull from B the commits on A.

In situations where "pull requests" often used, you have access to repo A but not to repo B. Hence you cannot use push. The only option is for you to "ask" somebody who has the write access to repo B (hence the term "request") to "pull" your commits on repo A.

Hence the term "pull request".